# External tool for test coverage for Visual Studio 2013 Professional

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I'd like to use some test coverage tool, but I only own Visual Studio 2013 Professional, which doesn't include built-in tool for test coverage for the unit tests.

Is there some free tool or at least something cheaper than additional $2000 on VS2013 Premium?

Answer (score 0):

dotCover from JetBrain is a good solution if you do not want to buy the Premium edition of MS Visual Studio.

They offer free edition for pen source projects and 30 days evaluation trial.